# Linear independence of two sets

Tags: linear-algebra

Let be $ V $ a vector space over a field $ \mathbb{K} $ and $ A:=\{v_1,...,v_n\}, B:=\{w_1,...,w_m\}\subseteq V $ two linear independent sets such that $ |A|<|B| $. Then there exists $ v\in B\setminus A $ such that $ \{v\} \cup A $ is linear independent.

I tried to proof it by contradiction:

Consider $ W:=\{w_i\in B:\ w_i\notin A, i\in I\subseteq \{1,...,m\}\} $ and assume that $ \{w_i\}\cup A $ is linear dependent for all $ w_i\in W $. Then there exist $ \lambda^{(i)}_1,...,\lambda^{(i)}_n $ such that
$$ w_i=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda^{(i)}_k\cdot v_k .$$

From here I havo no idea how to construct a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from your attempt:
You have shown that each $w_i$ is in $\text{span}(A)$. Thus, $\text{span}(B) \subseteq \text{span}(A)$, so $\dim(B) \le \dim(A)$. Since $B$ and $A$ are each linearly independent sets, this implies $|B| \le |A|$, a contradiction.

Comment: How do you come to $ \text{span}(B) \subseteq \text{span}(A) $? I only considered $ w_i\in W\subseteq B $.

Comment: You've shown that $w_i$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors from $A$. Consequently, any linear combination of $w_1, \ldots, w_n$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors from $A$.

Comment: I didn't show that for every $ w_i\in B $ just for every $ w_i\in W $ which doesn't imply $ \text{span}(B) \subseteq \text{span}(A) $ in general beacause $ W $ is just a subset of $ B $.

Comment: @hallo97 The $w_i$ that are not in your $W$ are by definition in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that this vector doesn't exists then for each set

$$C_i:=\{v_1,...,v_n, w_i\}$$

vectors are linearly dependent that is

$$w_i=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda^{(i)}_k\cdot v_k$$

then $$ \text{span}(B)=\text{span}(A)\implies \dim(\text{span}(B))=\dim(\text{span}(A)$$

which is a contradiction.